# How to estimate time spent in SAT solving part in z3 for SMT?

Tags: z3, smt, dpll

I have profiled my problems, which are in (pseudo-nonlinear) integer real fragment using the profiler gprof (stats [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/~jaideep/example2.stats) including the call graph) and was trying to separate out the time taken into two classes:

I)The SAT solving part (including [purely] boolean propagation and [purely] boolean conflict clause detection, backjumping, any other propositional manipulation)

II)The theory solving part (including theory consistency checks, generation of theory conflict-clauses and theory propagation).

Do lines 3280-3346 in [smt_context.cpp](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/smt/smt_context.cpp) within `bounded_search()` constitute the top-level DPLL(X) loop?

I believe it is easier to sum-up the time in SAT solver functions (since they are fewer)
and then the rest can be considered as theory solvers's time. I am trying to figure out which functions I should consider as falling under class I above? Are they `smt::context::decide()`, `smt::context::bcp()` within `smt::context::propagate()`? Any others?
`smt::context: resolve_conflict()` seems to be mixed with calls to theory solver?

Is it correct that `smt::context::propagate()` seems to be mostly theory propagation (class II) except its `bcp()` function? Also, `smt::context::final_check()` seems to be purely in class II.

Any hints greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, `bcp()` and `decide()` are part of the "SAT solver".
The function `final_check()` is just theory reasoning. It executes procedures that Z3 "claims" to be too "expensive". The `resolve_conflict()` procedure is mixed: it performs lemma learning, and backtracking. To generate new lemmas, Z3 uses Boolean resolution (which is in "SAT part"). In several cases, the most expensive part of `resolve_conflict` is backtracking the state of the theory solvers.

Comment: A clarification sought: `smt::conflict_resolution::resolve` is the lemma learning part you mentioned about (in the SAT part) and `smt::context::pop_scope_core()` does the expensive backtracking in the theory solvers, right?