# Trigger the running time of theory solver

Tags: z3

I want to trigger the running time of theory solver to see how much time does each theory checking take. Does anyone know which file and which variable do I need to look at? I don't know if the statistics method has this option.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28068323), [Christoph Wintersteiger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869966/christoph-wintersteiger) "expect[s] this to be nontrivial as it's not clear what exactly should and shouldn't be counted."

For the special case of Z3's SAT solver, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317330) by [Leonardo de Moura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841416/leonardo-de-moura) mentions several methods (such as `bcp()` and `decide()`) in a particular C++ file (`smt_context.cpp`) of Z3's sources that belong to this particular sub-solver.